# seeds.py file wont run on PostgresQL db, saying mapping is already generated?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, ponyorm

I have set up a simple PostgresQL database, named 'cooking-with-haynes', with a Flask and PonyORM app:

```
from flask import Flask
from pony.orm import Database

db = Database()
app = Flask(__name__)

db.bind('postgres', 'postgres://localhost:5432/cooking-with-haynes')

db.generate_mapping(create_tables=True)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return 'Hello World!', 200
```

...with a Recipe model:

```
from pony.orm import Required, Optional 
from app import db

class Recipe(db.Entity):
    name = Required(str)
    description = Required(str)
    photo = Optional(str)
    cooking_time = Required(int)
    prep_time = Required(int)
```

and a seeds.py file:

```
from pony.orm import db_session 
from app import db 
from models.recipe import Recipe

db.drop_all_tables(with_all_data=True) db.create_tables()

with db_session():

    # create some recipees
    Recipe(name="Lasagne", description="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.", cooking_time=60, prep_time=25)

    # save the data to the database
    db.commit()
```

When I run the seeds.py file to populate the database, i get the following error in my terminal:

```
pony.orm.core.ERDiagramError: Cannot define entity 'Recipe': database mapping has already been generated
```

I have used this method before and it has been fine: any any ideas why it isn't working?

I have dropped and created the database again; and I have made sure my flask app is running on my localhost.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're calling `db.generate_mapping()` before your declare your entites.
First you declare your Database object, then you declare entities, then bind database you call `generate mapping`. 
Also notice that `bind(...)` can be called at any time before `generate_mapping()`.